# Use magical methods to treat a class method as a property and vice-versa

Tags: php, laravel

Let's consider this `Product` model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        $this->belongsTo(Category::clas);
    }
}
```

With Laravel, I have the possibility to:

1. Get an instance of the `Query Builder` by doing

   ```
   $product = Product::first();
   $builder = $product->category()
   ```
2. Get an instance of the category by doing

   ```
   $product = Product::first();
   $category = $product->category
   ```

I know that this way of fetching either an instance of the Query Builder or category is purely PHP

After some research, I found out the `__call()` method so I used it as follow:

```
class Cart
{
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if($method) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I am unable to do this:

```
$cart = new Cart();
$cart->items
```

How can I manage my class to be able to do either `$cart->items` or `$cart->items()`

Comment: `$cart->items` will trigger the `__get` magic method and the `->items()` will trigger the `__call` magic method. The problem is that Laravel already has `__get` implemented in models so you'd be overriding the default (which may break your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

```
class Cart
{
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return "$name property";
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return "$name method";
    }
}

$cart = new Cart;

var_dump($cart->items); // => string(14) "items property"
var_dump($cart->items()); // => string(12) "items method"
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cec7fbfb66cfdc74da8e811d4f92867572264851).

Regarding Laravel models, you can override `__get` method, but be sure to add parent method call after your logic:

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if ($name === 'items') {
        // You logic here with an early return.
    }

    return parent::__get($name);
}
```